# Flash to Illustrator CC conversion... possible?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud

I've spent years drawing vector art in Flash, and recently decided to move to Illustrator (because that's really what I should have been using all along).

The trouble is, Flash art is strangely difficult to import into Illustrator. As recently as CS6, **the easiest way that I found was to open the FLA in Flash, export it as an FXG, open the FXG in Illustrator, and save it as an AI**.

Now in Illustrator CC, **when you try to open an FXG, you get the raw XML, and not the image**. So that puts a damper on this whole process.

Does anyone have any solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: If you do your regular process of transferring it into an older version of Illustrator first, save as an .ai, then update the version by opening and saving in CC, it should work.

Comment: Tried copy/paste between Flash and AI?

Comment: To add to @John's comment, if you have Illustrator CC, you also have the ability to download and install CS6, so you can do this workaround.

Comment: This is a major bummer. I work in flash quite often and just updated to CC - You would assume the programs would be improved to work together and not have features removed. I used the exprt to GFX quite a lot and now I dont have an easy work around. I hope this is fixed soon!

Comment: I haven't used Flash in a while, but I used to...a LOT...on a daily basis. It's a shame FXG doesn't work, I remember using it with CS6 and even gradients were nicely supported. The new Flash CC should support SVG export which you can open/edit with Illustrator. I'm not 100% sure all features will be supported (as Flash can implement drawing methods Illustrator doesn't). Alternatively, could you try uploading a swf of your drawing [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/sPjI) and see if the SWF comes out correctly ?

Answer (score 2):

Flash CC 2014 **can** export to SVG, and Illustrator CC 2014 **can** open an SVG. Works like a charm. All the layers come thru as separate objects.

***Original answer***

According [to someone on the Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5696693#5696693), Adobe claims FXG isn’t compatible with 64-bit. Seeing as Adobe did away with supporting 32-bit....

Adobe claims: “We will have vector export from Flash as one of the features for our next major update.” This same line has been repeated over and over again...for the last 9 months at least. Do a search for others running into the same difficulty.
Then, they recommend installing a third-party code to export as an SVG. Even if you feel brave enough to put on your programmer pants on to install the code, it only has been confirmed to work in some instances where the vector is simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can't export as SVG using the 'export' or 'save as' options. You can do it via the PUBLISH settings. Choose SVG there. Then click PUBLISH.

No idea why this can't just be an option in the EXPORT dialog since the capability is there within ANIMATE.

This is confirmed in ANIMATE CC 2018 on OSX

Answer (score -1):

Flash CC doesn't have the option to export SVG format, so here is the simple way to convert your file.

To import a Flash vector in Illustrator CC you need to export .swf from Flash and then go to this site http://riaxe.com/online-swf-to-svg-converter/ to convert the SWF to SVG format.

It works on several types of vector files, even if it has gradients and multi colors, it will give you the same layers and colors in Illustrator.

Comment: see comment from OP: _Update, a year later: Flash CC 2014 can export to SVG, and Illustrator CC 2014 can open an SVG._